# Query freebase /authority/imdb/title

Tags: freebase, imdb

How to query  namespace in freebase /authority/imdb/title by specific date range.

QUERY  /authority/imdb/title first date: 2013-10-10 second date: 2013-10-11, and get list of all IMDB ID's between this two dates?

Comment: Please see my answer to a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20356907/81821